# Trouble with singular value decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to calculate the singular value decomposition of the following $4\times 3$ matrix.

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\1&1&-1\\-1&1&0\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$

However, $A^TA$ turns out to be

$$A^TA=\begin{bmatrix}3&0&0\\0&3&0\\0&0&3\end{bmatrix}$$ with the only eigenvalue being $\lambda_1=3$

I don't know how I'm supposed to proceed in finding an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ of right singular vectors of $A$ in the case where the number of eigenvectors of $A^TA$ is less than the number of vectors in the columnspace of  $A$.

Comment: maybe this will help?: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=svd+%7B%7B1%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C-1%7D%2C%7B-1%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C1%7D%7D

Comment: I see that $A^TA$ has three linearly independent eigenvectors, $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$. Where is the problem?

Comment: Yep. For $\sum$, the one singular value occupies all the diagonals.